# Проходит сквозь объекты Rigidbody unity при отталкивании от других коллайдеров

Tags: c#, unity3d

На игроке Rigidody + capsule collider.
На стене - MeshCollider
Стена в виде полусферы(стенка трюма корабля)
При долгом и старательном беге в стену, когда на тебя одновременно воздействуют и отталкивают коллайдеры сверху и снизу( Верхняя и нижняя часть полусферы) ты можешь иногда пройти сквозь коллайдер. Получается как бы верхний коллайдер, отталкивая меня, пропихивает сквозь нижний и наоборот.

Тело двигаем через

```
Rigidbody.addForce
```

На твёрдом теле стоит ContiniousDynamic, интерполяцию пробовал разную, но, всё равно, когда долго меня так коллайдеры отталкивают друг на друга, иногда получается пролезть. Как избежать такого вообще?

Я видел прошлые похожие вопросы, везде суть ответов в передвижении предмета физикой(так и делаю), изменении типа столкновений на Dynamic(есть) и интерполяции-экстраполяции(пробовал).  А тут именно два коллайдера толкают друг на друга. Есть еще варианты решения такой проблемы?

Comment: А у вас на стене случайно Rigidbody не стоит? Если стоит - уберите, а коллайдер оставьте.

Comment: @Mike
Нет, на стене просто меш коллайдер, не конвекс даже. Своего Rigidbody  у него нет

Comment: А ради эксперимента box-коллайдер поставьте на стену. Будет проходить или нет.

Comment: @Mike Не проходит